# Is it possible to OCR (frame-by-frame) digital time and multimeter reading values from a video?

Tags: video, ocr

I have a time-lapse video that I need to collect data from (digital time and multimeter reading). Is anyone aware of any apps that can perform this kind of OCR?

The clock and multimeter screens are always in the same position with data in a known format, so it should be a much easier problem than general OCR, although the lighting does change.

Comment: Very interesting question. Found [this](https://waldo.jaquith.org/blog/2011/02/ocr-video/) online. Might help?

Comment: if you're looking for some software then this should be on [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: This might be acceptable on [softwarerecs.se] but you would need to read their [quality guidelines](https://softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/336/what-is-required-for-a-question-to-contain-enough-information) first as your question is missing a lot of information.